# Как мне сохранить значение из $_GET чтобы потом методом $_POST Обновить данные в php my admin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Как мне сохранить значение из `$_GET` чтобы потом методом `$_POST` Обновить данные в `phpmyadmin`?
что мне надо сделать чтобы значение в `$MainID` сохранилось для обновления данных в `phpmyadmin`?

**вот код ошибки**

> **Warning**:
> Undefined array key "ProgressID" in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\ravi\update.php on line 5

```
<?php
require_once 'config/connect.php';


$MainID = $_GET['ProgressID'];


$s_id ="";
$g_id = "";
$l = "";
$lab_grade = "";
$s_id_err = "";
$g_id_err ="";
$l_err = "";
$lab_grade_err = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $StudentID = trim($_POST["s_id"]);
    if(empty($StudentID)){
        $s_id_err = "Please choose student.";     
    } else{
        $s_id = $StudentID;
    }

    $GroupID = trim($_POST["g_id"]);
    if(empty($GroupID)){
        $g_id_err = "Please choose group.";     
    } else{
        $g_id = $GroupID;
    }

    $LabWork = trim($_POST["lab"]);
    if(empty($LabWork)){
        $l_err = "Please enter a number of laboratory work.";     
    } else{
        $l = $LabWork;
    }

    $LabGrade = trim($_POST["lab_grade"]);
    if(empty($LabGrade)){
        $lab_grade_err = "Please enter a grade of laboratory work.";     
    } elseif(filter_var($LabGrade, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>1, "max_range"=>20))) === false){
        $lab_grade_err = "Please enter a valid grade (from 1 to 20).";
    } else{
        $lab_grade = $LabGrade;
    }

    if(empty($g_id_err) && empty($l_err) && empty($lab_grade_err)){
        $sql = "UPDATE progress set s_id=:s_id, g_id = :g_id, lab = :lab, lab_grade = :lab_grade where progress_id = $MainID ";

        if($exec = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
            $exec->bindParam(":s_id", $student_id);
            $exec->bindParam(":g_id", $group_id);
            $exec->bindParam(":lab", $lab);
            $exec->bindParam(":lab_grade", $lab_grade);

            $student_id = $s_id;
            $group_id = $g_id;
            $lab = $l;
            $lab_grade = $lab_grade;
            if($exec->execute()){
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
        unset($exec);
    }
    unset($pdo);
}
?>
```

Comment: Какая то путаница. Во первых phpmyadmin это утилита управления базой данных MySQL. Она сама ничего не хранит. Во вторых. что у вас будет в переменных $_GET или $_POST зависит исключительно от кода в браузере пользователя (в виде форм и/или скрипта javascript). Вы ничего не можете хранить между вызовами от пользователя.

Comment: Обычной практикой является при запросе GET выдать браузеру в внутри html кода (или js кода) те значения, которые он вам сам вернет при следующем вызове. Т.е. например когда происходит GET вместе с формой отдаете `<input type=hidden name=MainID value='NNN'>`, а при POST он вам вместе с остальными полями отдаст и это значение MainID, которое у вас на этот  раз окажется в $_POST

Comment: @Mike огромное спасибо за ваш совет, решил проблему.

Comment: Что касается ошибки в самом начале, она от того что в $_GET['ProgressID'] ничего нет. Если вы обрабатываете GET запрос, то ваш скрипт должен вызываться как `/update.php?ProgressID=NNN`. А если он у вас предназначен для вызова POST, то и переменную надо искать в $_POST и разумеется предварительно передать ее туда со стороны html/js

Comment: И еще один совет. Отлично, что для выполнения запроса вы используете привязку переменных через bindParam, но почему при этом $MainID вы подставляете непосредственно в текст update, вместо :MainID и bind для него ? И как раз этот параметр вы в скрипте не проверяете на валидность ни как. Если  я передам в этот скрипт `ProgressID=1 or 1=1` то у вас в update получится `where  progress_id = 1 or 1=1` в итоге он изменит вообще все записи в БД, а не только ту что хотели. Эта атака называется SQL-инъекция. Все переменные в запросе надо проводить через bindParam что бы этого избежать